# htaccess rule is passing innecesary variable

Tags: .htaccess

This is the file tree:

- /problem/
- /problem/index.php
- index.php
- category.php
- somefile.php

I have this 2 rules in the .htaccess that is sitting in the /

```
RewriteRule ^somedir$ /somefile.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ /category.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So...

- http://domain.com/somedir = OK
- http://domain.com/ = OK
- http://domain.com/problem/ < automatically adds ?cat=problem to the querystring. **I want to avoid that extra ?cat=problem**

I need to add a rule that doesn't add the cat=$1 when the /dir/ exists.

Comment: What *should* it be passing then?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's doing exactly what you're telling it to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `RewriteCond` before your second rule. Basically, don't run that catch all if it starts with `product`:

```
RewriteRule ^somedir$ /somefile.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ /category.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

To prevent redirecting for a real file or directory, add these two lines before the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: that worked fine! is there a way to add a RewriteCond for all physical existing directories?